# MySQL count from two tables

Tags: java, mysql, count

I have two tables: loan and librarian.

librarian:
idLibrarian, libName and libPassword
loan:
idLoan,...,idLibrarian

Each loan has a idLibrarian.
What I'm trying to do is find which librarian has the most loans.
I can count number of librarians and number of loans. But i can't figure out how to group all the loans by idLibrarian and find the one with the highest amount of loans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select idLibrarian, count(*) from loan group by idLibrarian order by 2 desc
```

First row will be the librarian with the most loans, etc.

Comment: For some reason i get an error. This is what i've written:s.executeQuery("SELECT idLibrarian, COUNT(*) " +
    "FROM loan" +
    "GROUP BY idLibrarian" +
    "ORDER BY 2 DESC");

Comment: Looks like you are missing some whitespaces, between load and GROUP and between idLibrarian and ORDER. `"SELECT idLibrarian, COUNT(*) " + "FROM loan" + " GROUP BY idLibrarian " + "ORDER BY 2 DESC"`. Or you could skip concatenation and write it all in one string.